# Is it good practice to ensure cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't contain cell view modification code?

Tags: ios, uitableview, model-view-controller

I came upon this thought recently when I was working to add a 'dark/night' mode to my app.

Regularly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I would of course 'connect' my datasource to my newly created/reused cell.

Setting the cells data/strings/values etc, ready for display.

However, whilst cognisant of MVC, I myself, would sometimes set cell background colours or some other cell subview view related property (animations/colours/text style). - I'm working if this is truly a bad coding style?

During my work to create night mode, I moved **ALL** code related to view modification (colour/style/aesthetic) into each view class.

Then upon a reload of my tableView, I setup up each cell and **finally call their new function to layout their aesthetics** - which now lives inside the cell class.

Ergo, my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has a single call to the cell instance to change its look and feel, and the rest of the code is purely setting data on the cell.

- Is this the pure MVC approach?
- Is this good practice?
- Is it acceptable to be calling my tableView's reload method *in order to trigger* a call to update the cell as needed, whenever my viewController wants to change look and feel, or should I be keeping a reference to each cell separately?

Comment: Seems perfectly normal. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: Personally I'm trying to schedule cell for reuse at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and setup cell controls via `willDsipayCell`- it make code more clean, or If it are few different kinds, call specific `configureCellFor<Purpose>` from `willDispay`

Comment: Downvoting this question is ridiculous. It’s either MVC or it’s not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is pretty subjective.

On my opinion in most cases the outlets of cell should be private to the cell's class, and not expose unneeded info to the viewController. I prefer creating several methods within the cell's class such as: `func populate(_ with: SomeDataType)` - for populating the cell. This way the cell is much more encapsulated and reusable.

> Is it acceptable to be calling my tableView's reload method in order
>   to trigger a call to update the cell as needed, whenever my
>   viewController wants to change look and feel, or should I be keeping a
>   reference to each cell separately

Yes it is acceptable, in fact there are pretty rare cases that you need to keep references to reusable elements, such as `UITableViewCell`'s instances. Please take a look at the section `Reloading the Table View` from the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) or `func reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)` [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows)

EDIT 1:
I feel like you can benefit from going trough this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html 
The main goal is: Try to understand what is "reuseIdentifier" and why UITableView reuses cells instead of creating new views every time that cell should be displayed. Once you get this, you will understand why saving reference to tableViewCell is tricky.

Comment: Got it, I agree and understand the reuse paradigm. Not looking to keep references to all cells, inelegant indeed. thank you!